# Appending each element in a (string) list, to each element in another (string) list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, list-comprehension

Some context:
I have a dataset from 14 samples that each are comprised of two duplicate parts. Each duplicate part of each sample has sub-samples, and each of these have a location in which can be described by an x and y position where n x=10 and n y=10 (100 positions, per 2 duplicates, per 14 samples = 2800 Unique IDs).

So, each sub-sample has a unique ID that is comprised of `sample'+'part'+'locationx'+'locationy`. Note this is not a product (I think!?) but a joined string comprised of each possible combination. Each unique ID has considerable amounts of numerical data attached to it. I wish to generate a list of the unique ID of each sub-sample, so that I can then use this to loop code efficiently. The unique IDs would be tedious to write out, for instance as a nested list.

I have read many posts about how to add a string to each element in a list. This can be achieved by a List Comprehension. That would speed things up. But, what about if you want to add each string in a list to each string in another list? That would speed things up mightily!

This sounds a little like building a multidimensional array, which can be achieved using lists, but not if those lists are strings (it seems to me!), only integers. I hope I'm wrong and someone can tell me so.

A downsized description of the concept using just two lists:

```
    list1 = ['foo', 'fob', 'faz']
    list2 = ['bar', 'bat', 'bump']
```

*magic*

```
    list3 = ['foobar', 'fobbar', 'fazbar', 'foobat', 'fobbat', 'fazbat', 'foobump', 'fobbump', 'fazbump']
```

Comment: Briefly: join each result of the Cartesian product.

Comment: @Ann I think ``'sample'+'part'+'locationx'+'locationy'`` was supposed to be `sample+part+locationx+locationy`

Comment: @wjandrea Oh, you're right, sorry :)

Comment: Thanks so much, but yes I do want to join the results @TigerhawkT3, so I've modified the question. Pointing to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists) really helped me. But, I'm after a list of all possible joined combinations. Do I put a join function somewhere?

Comment: You can concatenate strings with the `+` operator, or concatenate an iterable containing strings together with `str.join`.

Comment: TigerhawkT3 this is excellent, many thanks. I'll go and try this now.

Comment: TigerhawkT3 it works with an append command, supplemented by a strip
UniqueIDs = []
>>> for i in UniqueID_tuples:
...    UniqueIDs.append(''.join(i).strip())

no doubt this is not news to you, but wanted to say thanks again.